# How to toggle between text in animation for different devices? html/css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I want to reuse the code and make it work for both mobile devices and other devices. Specifically, when I am on a mobile device I want the same animation but with different text to appear and when I am on a laptop or desktop, I want the same animation with different text to appear.

So essentially, there should be one single animation but it should have text that works differently for mobile devices and another text that works for laptops or desktops or larger screens.

Code:

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

(function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    var banner;
    banner = document.querySelector('.exponea-banner3');
    banner.classList.add('exponea-in3');
    return banner.querySelector('.exponea-close3').addEventListener('click', function() {
      return banner.classList.remove('exponea-in3');
    });
  });

}).call(this);
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500");
html3,
body3 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.exponea-banner3 {
 
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 30px rgba(116, 119, 176, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  display: none;
}
.exponea-banner3.exponea-in3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-close3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-label3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-text3 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-count3 {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.exponea-banner3 .exponea-label3 {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner3,
.exponea-close3,
.exponea-text3,
.exponea-label3,
.exponea-label3 {
    z-index: 10;
}
.open3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="exponea-banner3 open3">
        <div class="exponea-close3">
            &times;
        </div>
        <div class="exponea-text3">
            Hi There! Thanks For Stumbling Upon My Website!
        </div>
        <div class="exponea-label3">
            - Hussain Omer
        </div>
    </div>
```

The text in the above animation should only work on **laptops/desktops/larger screens**

---

Now, I want the **same** animation but the **different** text that says "Hi, please use a large device for the best experience" to work **only** on mobile devices.

When the user is on the mobile device, the text should say what I said above and when the user is on laptops/desktops/large screen then the text should say what I sent in the code. Any suggestions on how I can toggle the text in the animation?

tl;dr: I want the same animation but when the user is on a mobile device, it should have a text saying "Hi, please use a large device for the best experience" but when the user is on a laptop/desktop or large screen device, then the text should say what it is in the code I sent above.

### Update

This is what my output looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKVq3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to check media queries and change text accordingly.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

// Media query example
const isMobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 360px)')

(function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    var banner;
    banner = document.querySelector('.exponea-banner3');

    if(isMobile) {
       document.querySelector(".exponea-text3").textContent = "Hi, please use a large 
        device for the best experience"
    }

    banner.classList.add('exponea-in3');
    return banner.querySelector('.exponea-close3').addEventListener('click', function() {
      return banner.classList.remove('exponea-in3');
    });
  });

}).call(this);
});
```

Comment: can you show a snippet or something because it does not work on my end

Comment: did you try with different media query?

Comment: no i did not try it with different media query

Comment: `const isMobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 360px)')` here I am checking for min width of 360. set your dev tools with appropriate numbers.

Comment: ok one sec, I will also update my post with what I a getting

Comment: I have updated my post with what my output looks like

Comment: hey, did u see it?